# How to fix bug in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I was adding file XML for new activity but I clicked some wrong and changed to CMake file... I tried remove and add new file again but it still stuck to CMake it looks bug or some. I uninstalled and installed but it still stuck.

Screenshot:

[image: List of layout]

Comment: Take a look at this https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206074809-How-to-change-the-file-type-of-a-single-file-

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now it works. How I can accept your answer here?

Comment: Oh it was only a comment, you can just close unanswered questions if you like